# What does "<>" mean in C programming?

Tags: c

I saw this example in an If statement `y<>3` and I was wondering what it does.

Comment: this whole line is just garbage

Comment: If you had tried to compile it you would have seen that it does not mean anything.

Comment: my question is not how to do the exercise but what <> means in C, I just posted the exercise for people to see how is implemented in code, Hyde.

Comment: Did you compile the code and see for yourself? What have you tried?

Comment: @Jaycoder Why do you assume that it means anything? It's like asking what `if(!"#¤%&/)` would mean.

Comment: where did you see it? this does not make sense. It could be mistype or just mistake, for example in some languages '<>' means 'not equal', but in C you have to use '!='

Comment: That's why I was asking, because i dont know if it means anything.

Comment: `<>` is not a C operator although it is in the BASIC language. In C that would be `!=`.

Comment: @Jaycoder Before asking such a question, you should at least try to compile it. If it compiles and you don't understand, then you have a valid question. But since it does not even compile the answer is simply that it does not mean anything.

Comment: Klutt, compiling was the first thing I did. But I did not give a clear error in the console log. That's why I asked

Comment: @Jaycoder That's strange. I get `error: expected expression before ‘>’ token` which is a quite clear indicator that it is wrong. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have to check if this exercise is correct

It is not.

```c
if (((x < y) && (y < z)) && (y != 3))
    printf(“%f < %d < %d \n”, x, y, z);
```

Is correct, assuming `float x` and `int y, z`.

`<>` in some languages means "does not equal". But in c, the operator is `!=`. Also note the difference between logical AND (`&&`) and bitwise AND (`&`). You should use the logical operators for multiple criteria in a conditional statement.